# ReGex - matching a logical implication

Tags: regex

Given the alphabet `{a, b, c}`, how can I create a simple regular expression which matches exactly those words which meet the following criteria:

- If the string "aa" occurs, then consequently "cc" must also occur (Note the logical implication).
- The order of occurence doesn't matter ("cc" as well as "aa" can occur first).

Due to the former logical implication (if-then relationship), the string "cc" can occur even without "aa", but not vice versa. 
I am looking for a way to implement this by using these syntax elements `(., *, +, ?, |, )` as well as brackets.

Example what should be matched:

- cc
- abba
- bccb
- bccaa
- ε (epsilon - empty string)

What shouldn't be matched:

- aa
- aacbcb
- abaaba
- baaa
- caac

I have tried the following: `a?b?(ba)*(ccaa)*(aacc)*c*b?`

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: `(cc)|(?!aa)` and you do the rest :p

Comment: I have tried the following:
a?b?(ba)*(ccaa)*(aacc)*c*b?

Comment: try this small soft to test http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ and use this http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Try using `p -> q <=> !p v q`.

Comment: @Abdelouahab This is homework. Therefore the regex flavor is "academic" which doesn't support fancy lookaround.

Comment: Your matching examples are inconsistent with the explanation. "abba" doesn't have the "aa" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I should answer this, since it's homework, but here goes...

First of, you identify the clauses P:*"string 'aa' occurs"* and Q:*"string 'cc' occurs"*. Then you transform `P -> Q` into `!P v Q`. Then you translate this into the regular expression formed of the two parts:

```
^(((b|c)*(a(b|c)+)*a?)|(.*cc.*))$
```

The first part denies any 'aa' groups, and goes like this: allow any number of `b`s and `c`s at the beginning (including none), then if you find an `a`, force at least one different character after it. `a`s followed by non `a`s may happen any number of times. At the end we also have the `a?` to allow for the string to end in an `a` and we are sure it has no `a` before it because none of the 2 preceding groups end in `a`.

The second part is trivial.

Test it here: http://rubular.com/r/mAPHO8bulo
See it here: [http://jex.im/regulex/...](http://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%28%28.*cc.*%29%7C%28%28b%7Cc%29*%28a%28b%7Cc%29%2B%29*a%3F%29%29%24)

Comment: I have struggled a lot with this question and almost had the same solution as you, though I couldn't figure out how to match the a's, now I understand.
Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: @Sunshine Regexes are by nature positive, so you need to accurately identify the opposite of what you don't want to match and describe that.

Comment: Another way to write the first part is: `(a?(b|c))*a?`